# C++ string initialization

Tags: c++

I've seen a statement according to which

```
string noun("ants");
string noun = "ants";
```

are exactly equivalent.

This is contrary to my intuition: I thought in the second case a conversion occurs (via a constructor of the `string` class), then the assignment operator gets called with an argument of class `string`. What is there actually happening ?

Comment: C++ is happening, that's what. It's initialization in both cases, so no call to `op=` is made. Compare to `string noun; noun = "ants";`

Comment: As the saying goes: Initialization is not assignment.

Comment: There's no assignment anywhere, but the two are still not exactly equivalent; see Joachim Pileborg's answer.

Comment: this is why you should add a copy constructor to your classes. Some people add an assignment operator and wonder why it is never called.

Comment: @clambake Or ban copy and assignment.  (This is what I do most of the time for polymorphic types.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For initialization of a variable definition using assignment, like

```
std::string a = "foo";
```

Here two objects are created: The variable you define (`a` in my example) and a temporary object (for the string `"foo"`). Then the copy-constructor of your variable (`a`) is called with the temporary object, and then the temporary object is destructed. The copy-assignment operator is not called.

However, the copying can be avoided if the compiler uses [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision), which is an optimization technique to avoid unnecessary copies and copying. The copy-constructor needs to be there anyway, even if it's not called.

---

For the definition

```
std::string a("foo");
```

there is a better [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) which takes a pointer to a constant string, which the literal `"foo"` can be seen as (string literals are actually constant arrays of `char`, but like all arrays they decay to pointers).

Comment: Agreed, "copy constructor" gets called in both cases.

Comment: This is not what happens. Two objects are *not* created.

Comment: @Michael Conceptually, yes.  The standard contains special language which allows the compiler to elide the extra object, even if it cannot prove that the copy constructor only copies, and most, if not all implementations do.

Comment: @Michael, try `delete`ing the copy-constructor or making it `private`, then your compiler should give an error for the second version.

Answer (score 3):

I thought it would be harder to find, but here goes:

**§12.6.1 Explicit initialization ([class.expl.init])**

```
complex a(1);   // initialize by a call of
                // complex(double)
complex b = a;  // initialize by a copy of a
```

As **@pmr** pointed out, *initialization is not assignment*, thus no call to an assignment operator is made. Refer to the rest of `12.6.1` for details.

Valuable information can also be found in **§8.5 ([dcl.init])**, with **8.5.1** denoting

```
initializer:
    brace-or-equal-initializer
    ( expression-list )
brace-or-equal-initializer:
    = initializer-clause
    braced-init-list
```

and **8.5.2** showing examples of *initializers*.

<sub>Disclaimer: I only had n3485 laying around, but I doubt it changed in C++14</sub>